$E$ is finite-dimensional Euclidean space over $\mathbb{R}, x \in E, x \neq 0$. Then $\{Ax: A = A^* \succeq 0, \|A\| \leq 1\}$ is a closed ball
Let $E$ be a finite-dimensional Euclidean space over $\mathbb{R}$ and let $x \neq 0$ be a vector in $E$. Show that the set $K=\{Ax: A = A^* \succeq 0, \|A\| \leq 1\}$ is the closed ball of radius $\frac{|x|}{2}$ centered at $\frac{x}{2}$
We note a couple of things: First, as $A$ is positive definite, then since $x \neq 0$ by assumption, we have that $(Ax, x) > 0$ where $( \cdot, \cdot )$ is the usual Euclidean inner product. So if we write $x = \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n a_ie_i$ for basis vectors $e_1,\dots, e_n$ and $a_i \in \mathbb{R}$, then $Ax = \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n a_iA(e_i)$; the positive-definiteness means that
$$(Ax,x) > 0 \iff \begin{pmatrix} b_1 \\ \vdots \\ b_n \\ \end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} a_1 \\ \vdots \\ a_n \\ \end{pmatrix} = \sum_{i=1}^n b_ia_i > 0$$
where $b_i = a_iA(e_i)$ Second, regarding $A = A^*$, we note that $A: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$, so if we identify $A$ with $A = (a_{ij})$, then $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix and $A^*$ is the conjugate transpose of $A$. But the space is over $\mathbb{R}$; thus,
$$A= A^* = (\overline{a_{ji}}) = (a_{ji}) = A^T$$
giving that $A = (a_{ij})$ as a matrix is symmetric. This concludes my observations. To complete the problem, I suspect that one method would be to suppose the set $K$ has a different radius and different center and derive contradiction(s) from this. Or maybe there is a more clever way to do this, using inequalities to bound the radius and to find the center.
Unfortunately, I am unsure of how to approach such a daunting problem. What can be done here?

The condition $(Ax,x)>0$ means that all possible images $Ax$ via non-nogative symmetric operators are in the half-space $\{y: (y,x)>0\}$.
Pick any direction $u$ in that half-space. The orthogonal projection operator $P_u$ onto the one-dimensional subspace generated by $u$ belongs to your class (is one of your $A$’s, with $\|P_u\|=1$), therefore we obtain all possible projections onto all possible directions in that half-space. Those form a sphere centered at $x/2$ with radius $\|x\|/2$, by Thales’ Theorem.
We can get all the points in the solid ball by considering multiples of the orthogonal projections $\alpha P_u$ with $0\le \alpha\le 1$.
It remains to check that no point outside of the ball is obtained in this way. Both $A$ and $A^2$ diagonalize in some orthonormal basis. If $(x_1,\dots x_n)$ are the coordinates of $x$ in that basis, and $\lambda_i\le 1$ are the eigenvalues of $A$, we have
$$
\|Ax\|^2=(Ax,Ax)=(A^TAx,x)=(A^2x,x)=
$$
$$
=\lambda_1^2x_1^2+\dots+\lambda_n^2x_n^2\le \lambda_1x_1^2+\dots+\lambda_nx_n^2=(Ax,x),
$$
(Since $\lambda_i^2\le \lambda_i$), which  implies
$$
\|Ax\|\le \frac{\|x\|(Ax,x)}{\|x\|\|Ax\|}
$$
Or
$$
\|Ax\|\le \|x\|\cos\angle(x,Ax),
$$
But this is precisely the condition that all possible images $Ax$ lie in the above ball.
This concludes the proof.

I assume that $E=\mathbb R^n$ with $n\ge2$, as the one-dimensional case is easy. By scaling $K$ and the closed ball by the same factor, I also assume that $x$ is a unit vector.
For any $A$ such that $0\preceq A\preceq I$, we have $A^2-A\preceq0$. Therefore
$$
\left\|Ax-\frac{x}{2}\right\|^2
=\langle (A^2-A)x,x\rangle + \left\|\frac{x}{2}\right\|^2
\le\left\|\frac{x}{2}\right\|^2.
$$
This shows that $\|v-\frac{x}{2}\|\le\frac{1}{2}$ for any $v\in K$.
Conversely, suppose $\|v-\frac{x}{2}\|\le\frac{1}{2}$.
Pick a unit vector $y$ such that $y\perp x$ and $v\in\operatorname{span}\{x,y\}$. Express $v-\frac{x}{2}$ as a linear combination $ax+by$. Define a linear map $H$ by $Hx=v-\frac{x}{2}=ax+by,\,Hy=bx-ay$ and $H=0$ on $\left(\operatorname{span}\{x,y\}\right)^\perp$. Then $H$ is self-adjoint and $\|H\|=\|Hx\|=\|v-\frac{x}{2}\|\le\frac{1}{2}$. Therefore $0\preceq A\preceq I$ when $A=H+\frac{I}{2}$. Consequently $v=Hx+\frac{x}{2}=Ax\in K$.
